# Mais atributos no AppSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, arquivo, webforms

É possível adicionar outros valores ao `AppSettings` sem romper com a aplicação?

Valores padrões:

```
<appSettings> 
    <add key="Nome" value="ValorTeste" /> 
</appSettings>
```

Gostaria de deixá-lo assim:

```
<appSettings> 
    <add key="Nome" value="ValorTeste" roles="TESTE" title="TESTE" />
</appSettings>
```

Os novos valores serão gravados por uma aplicação externa.

Answer (score 3):

Dentro do app settings você pode por apenas Chave e Valor.

Tente utilizar várias settings diferentes.

Exemplo:

```
<appSettings> 
    <add key="Nome" value="ValorTeste" />
    <add key"Teste" value="Teste" />
</appSettings>
```

Para recuperar um item dentro do código C#, use:

```
var nome = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Nome"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que ficaria assim:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="Nome" value="ValorTeste" />
 <add key="Rules" value="TESTE" />
 <add key="Title" value="Teste" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Apenas Nome e Valor

> É possível adicionar outros valores ao AppSettings sem romper com a
>   aplicação?

A resposta para sua pergunta, para incluir novos atributos, é **não**. Isso acontece porque a o `appSettings` é uma serialização da [`NameValueCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que é uma coleção de itens que tem um nome e um valor.

Se você precisa de uma alternativa de configuração você pode usar uma implementação de uma seção de configuração própria da sua aplicação estendendo a classe [`ConfigurationSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx). Fazendo isso você constrói classes com os seus próprios parâmetros e evolui conforme a sua aplicação for crescendo.

Além do exemplo da própria MS, [nessa resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7983216/1700943) tem um exemplo simples de implementação.